# Cómo agregar y analizar código JAVA con sonarqube

Tags: java, sonar

Recientemente encontré SONARQUBE.
Pareciera ser lo quenecesito, pero no logro comprenderlo por completo.

Al ingresar a localhost:9000 puedo ver el panel e ingresar como admin, pero no logro añadir un proyecto java que tengo que analizar.

Tampoco encontré ningún tutorial que me funcione.

Alguien sabe cómo debo proseguir?

Saludos!

Comment: Si, se añaden principalmente por los gestores y constructores de proyecto (Maven, ANT) existen varios tutoriales al respecto https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven

Comment: @Ajeno Gracias por la respusta! vi la documentación, pero sigo sin poder entenderla. Lo que tengo es una aplicación descomplilada (el código es JAVA) y necesito correr un escaneo para evaluar su código. La verdad no entiendo mucho de esto. Tienes un ejemplo práctico para que pueda seguir? Gracias!

Comment: primero necesito saber que utilizas si ant, maven, gradle, etc, en la documentación vienen los ejemplos que deberías aplicar, el de Maven es uno de los más sencillos, si desconoces que es Maven o Ant primero darle una checada a ellos.

Comment: Eso debería saberlo el desarrollador? Yo no hice la aplicación. Sólo me la dieron para que busque un analizador de códig estático. Busqué y encontré SONARQUBE :(

Comment: Si, deberás apoyarte con el desarrollador, ya que deberás hacerle cambios al archivo build.xml (ant) o pom.xml (Maven), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear un proyecto, ingresar un Nombre cualquiera y luego presionar "Set Up".

Después, para generar el token, presionas en "Locally": ahí igual puedes colocar cualquier nombre. Presionas en continuar y Sonarqube te mostrar cómo puede analizar el código fuente.

Debería ser algo como esto:

```
mvn clean verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=NombreIngresado -Dsonar.host.url=http://IP_SERVER/ -Dsonar.login=6df769f05b39a496c09095bbe784eb9496802f28
```

Este comando deberías ejecutarlo en un proyecto Maven, y en la lista de proyectos podrás ver el resultado del análisis.